# SweetAlert doesn't display content markup

Tags: 8, modal-dialogs

The SweetAlert modal is not displaying the content as passed in the option array when returning a response from the controller. Please see the code config below:

```
//$options                      = array();
    $options                        = SweetAlertCommand::defaultOptions();
    $options['title']   = 'Appointment Details';
    $options['html']        = TRUE;
    $options['content'] = '<div class="row">'.
                                                  '<div class="modal-item col-sm-3">'.
                                                    '<p class="txt">Last Name</p>'.
                                                    '<p class="item-details">'.$results['last_name'].'</p>'.
                                                  '</div>'.
                                                  '<div class="modal-item col-sm-3">'.
                                                    '<p class="txt">First Name</p>'.
                                                    '<p class="item-details">'.$results['first_name'].'</p>'.
                                                  '</div>'.
                                                  '<div class="modal-item col-sm-3">'.
                                                    '<p class="txt">Email ID</p>'.
                                                    '<p class="item-details">'.$results['email'].'</p>'.
                                                  '</div>'.
                                                  '<div class="modal-item col-sm-3">'.
                                                '</div>';

    $response                   = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new SweetAlertCommand($options));
    return $response;
```

When the alert is triggered the alert comes as blank. Any leads? I am using the sweetalert module https://www.drupal.org/project/sweetalert

Comment: I dont know of an option called 'content'. The module was written against version 1 of Sweet Alert. https://sweetalert.js.org/ . But looking here, it looks like content was not meant in that way? https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/

Comment: @Kevin Correct. As per version 1 we have "text" instead of "content" however that is also not working. The alert comes as blank. The html string in "text" is not being rendered.

Comment: Not sure what to say, unless there is a browser console error or application error logged somewhere. It works/worked for me.

Comment: I dont see any errors in console. Can you share your php code definition for this sweetalert? @Kevin